# Can't define prototype cells in UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, ios5

I am working with a tableview in Xcode. When I try to set the content type setting and the number of prototype cells setting, they are not there. The settings page should be like:

[image: The settings page should be like:]

But it looks like:

[image]

as you can see there is no content setting. Why not?

Comment: Is it a storyboard file or just a xib file? If I'm not mistaken, the new options for prototype cells only appear in storyboard.

Comment: I was asking if the file you are editing the tableview in is a .storyboard file or a .xib file

Comment: @iJordan I believe you have the answer there, you should post it as such.

Comment: @jrturton done. just wanted to probe first.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're trying to edit it through a xib file which does not have the same options as a storyboard file.

Comment: i think i got it, but now i have a different problem, i get tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector whenever i run the application.

Comment: you need to properly set up the UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate methods. One of the required methods is that one.